# How to get rid of the extra space flex-wrap creates

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a dropdown menu with flex, when there are more than 6 items the items will be 50% wide and less than 6 they will be 100% wide.

The parent container should have a maximum width and should shrink if they are not many items. 
 So I got that working, but I cannot seem to get rid of the extra 'space' on the right of the 100% wide items. Does anyone have an idea to solve this? The extra space grows larger if the items have much text in it, making it rather unnecessary big.

```css
ul {
  background: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 0;
  align-content: start;
}

li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* If there are less than 6 */
li:nth-last-child(-n+6):first-child,
li:nth-last-child(-n+6):first-child ~ li {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  min-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it would be tricky to solve with flexbox but you can easily achieve the same using float without the extra whitespace:

```css
ul {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}

/* If there are less than 6 */
li:nth-last-child(-n+6):first-child,
li:nth-last-child(-n+6):first-child ~ li {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Or CSS grid:

```css
ul {
  background: red;
  display: inline-grid;
  column-gap:5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column:2;
}

/* If there are less than 6 */
li:nth-last-child(-n+6):first-child ~ :nth-child(2) {
  grid-column:initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>hello</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am so busy with flexbox these days I didn't even thought about floats! Thank you, if I cannot get it to work with flexbox I will definitely use this.

Comment: @CaptainFurball I also added a CSS grid solution, can be easier if you want to handle the gaps

Comment: Thank you! I will probably go for the float solution (for compatibility) but it is nice to have a grid example as well.